# Одна или две н, нужен ли дефис?

Tags: дефис

...Воссоздал утонченную атмосферу японских центров красоты с продуманно простыми интерьерами, в которых царит...

Добрый день! Подскажите, одна или 2 "н"? Возможно, нужен дефис?

Comment: А в каком слове?

Answer (score 3):

Всё верно, -НН-, т.к. наречие продуманно образовано от отглагольного прилагательного продуманный. Ни тире, ни дефиса нет. Это отдельное наречие и отдельное прилагательное, не оттенок.